# Issue with installing imblearn package

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, imblearn

#### Attempting from Jupyter

[image: Installing using jupyter]

#### Attempting from Conda prompt

[image: Installing using Conda prompt]

I'm trying to install `imblearn` package, but I keep getting this error. Any solutions would be helpful. I'm kinda new to Python, so I don't know a lot about package installation.

Comment: Looking at you 'Conda Prompt' screenshot, you can see a section 'Specifications'. There it shows you that you have a too new version of python. Use Conda to downgrade your python version from your 3.8 to 3.6.*.

Comment: Just as a tip for programming (or python) debugging in general. Errors usually look very intimidating, with a bunch of stuff no one can read. But almost always there is just a small snippet of text that says exactly what is wrong, and where. This snippet is hidden between all the giberish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Conda Forge. The package name is `imbalanced-learn`. Try installing with

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: Optionally you can add `%` in front of that and run it in a cell in the notebook, too. I see OP was using outdated `!pip install` in a notebook. Avoid the exclamation point; that is outdated for `pip`. A magic command for `pip` and `conda` has been added into modern Jupyter to help handle installation into correct environment, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).